# JS: concatenating html (with +) -> only print html if condition is true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

didn't quite know how to title this question. 
My problem might be fairly simple but I don't know the correct and working solution.

```
if ( rt > 0 ) retweets = '<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>';

var tweet = 
'<article class="item tweet">' +
    '<h4 class="tweet_from_user_name">' + tw.from_user_name +
    '<p class="tweet_text">' + tw.text + '</p>' +
    retweets + 
'<article>';

$('#twitter').html(tweet);
```

So the problem I have is this. I'm printing a tweet with "Username" the "Text of the Tweet" and want to display the "Retweets" but only if they are available.

So I don't want to write "0 Retweets" but rather just don't display the `<div>` that contains the retweets.

How can I make sure that the `retweets` variable isn't printet if `rt` is smaller 0. Right now this would work. However the only thing is, that `retweets` now is undefined if `rt` is smaller than 0.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one short way without any extra variables:

```
var tweet = 
'<article class="item tweet">' +
    '<h4 class="tweet_from_user_name">' + tw.from_user_name +
    '<p class="tweet_text">' + tw.text + '</p>' +
    (rt > 0 ? '<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>' : '') + 
'<article>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var retweets = "";
if ( rt > 0 ) retweets = '<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
retweets = (rt > 0) ? ('<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>') : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `retweets` to an empty string if there's no retweets

```
if ( rt > 0 ) {
    retweets = '<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>';
} else {
    retweets = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a ternary

```
var tweet = 
'<article class="item tweet">' +
    '<h4 class="tweet_from_user_name">' + tw.from_user_name +
    '<p class="tweet_text">' + tw.text + '</p>' +
    (rt > 0 ? retweets : "") + 
'<article>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
retweets = (rt > 0) ? '<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>' : '';
```

Basically, set it to an empty string if `rt` is less than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if statement

```
if ( rt > 0 ) retweets = '<div class="stats"><b>' + rt + '</b> Retweets</div>';

var tweet = 
'<article class="item tweet">' +
    '<h4 class="tweet_from_user_name">' + tw.from_user_name +
    '<p class="tweet_text">' + tw.text + '</p>';
if rt > 0 {
 var tweet+= retweets
}
var tweet+='<article>';

$('#twitter').html(tweet);
```